# Condition of quotient space to satisfy T1 axiom

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

Here are the definitions that were given in Munkres's general topology:

**Definition 1:** A topological space satisifes the T1 axiom if every finite point set is closed.

**Definition 2:** Let $X$ be a topological space, and let $X^*$ be a partition of $X$ into disjoint subsets whose union is $X$. Let $p:X \to X^*$ be the surjective map that carries each point of $X$ to the element of $X^*$ containing it. In the quotient topology induced by $p$, the space $X^*$ is called a quotient space of $X$.

**Question:** I'm currently stuck on one statement that says in order for $X^*$ to satisfy the T1 axiom, one simply requires that each element of the partition $X^*$ be a closed subset of $X$. I'm not quite sure how is this true. Can anyone explain this to me? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

By definition the quotient topology consists of all $U\subset X^*$ such that $p(U)^{-1}$ is open in $X$, so also for every closed $C\subset X^*$, we have that its preimmage is closed.

Knowing this, if we get an element $x^*\in X^*$ we have that it is a class of elements of $X$, in other terms it means $x^*=A\subset X$, so if we show that $A$ is closed, then by definition $\{ x^* \}$ is closed in $X^*$.

This is what we wanted, if fact a finite union of closed subset is closed.

Comment: How do you know the union is finite?